# Upgrade SQL database with merge replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, merge, replication

We are planning to upgrade SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012 and both the database is hosted on two different servers.

SQL Server 2005 has around 25 merge publication and have around 400 laptops that subscribe to these publication. The new SQL server 2012 will also have same replication setup as the old server. The data base size on the existing server is 66 GB and takes about 1.5 hrs for initial sync up.

Due to various business constraints we can't move over to new server in a single switch. Instead we need to keep both the servers running for a month or two. During this process, we need to replicate(uni-directional) data from SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2012 on a daily basis. To achieve this we have tried the following approaches so far:

1. DB backup and restore from SQL 2005 to SQL 2012 server - In this approach, the publications are dropped by SQL 2012 after we restore.
2. SQL native replication - Could not setup Transactional, Merge and Snapshot replication due SQL constraints. Cannot setup merge replication between SQL 2005(publisher) and SQL 2012(subscriber)

We are looking for different options to setup server to server replication with given constraints. Can SQL gurus help give some pointers?

Comment: Not only is this an upgrade, but is also a migration to new hardware, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, we are also migrating to a new hardware.